# How to generate numbering per-group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  a table with columns `Name` and `unit`.

A customer may have multiple unit.
I want to set `sl` no dynamically in sql like below image.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: You should have searched for it first. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By .... Order by...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By name Order by unit) as sl,
name,Unit
from tablename
```

Comment: For the sake of quality of SO, I believe we shouldn't provide answers for such basic questions which also does not show any efforts towards solving it.

Comment: @RagingBull Yes you are right but all user should not understand some function

Comment: You can just close this question as duplicate. @RagingBull

Comment: @MukeshKalgude: That is why I gave him an hint as a comment under his question. Spoon feeding won't do anything good in his career. Let him find the solution by himself. We can guide him towards answer. BTW, it wasn't me who downvoted your answer (just some guy who cares the quality of SO). Didn't upvote either.